# Merging 2 seperate list with different lengths without index

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration

The 2 different list have 2 different lengths. so i would want to merge them based off the score.

My example output is show below

```
list1 = [
    "ld Liked", "ld Disliked", "ld Liked", "ld Liked", "ld Disliked",
    "ld Liked", "ld Disliked", "ld Liked", "ld Disliked", "ld Disliked",
    "ld Liked", "ld Disliked", "ld Liked"
]

list2 = [
    "score   10", "score   10", "score   10", "score   8.0", "score   10",
    "score   6.0", "score   10", "score   8.0"
]


example of the output must be as follows after match
 
list[0] = liked and disliked : 10
list[1] = liked : 10
list[2] = liked and disliked : 10
list[3] = liked and disliked : 8.0
list[4] = liked and disliked : 10
list[5] = disliked : 6.0
list[6] = liked and disliked : 10
list[7] = liked : 8.0
```

I tried using zip to iterate them and some if statements to check if it matches but it dosent work

The purpose of my output is to match the reviews against the scoring as each "review" has only a single score but there may consist a liked and disliked string.

So as shown in my example the scoring would check if the review has a LIKE or DISLIKE and treat it as a singular entity.

Each review will start with a Like unless there is no Like it will only have a Dislike like based off my example output

Comment: Please provide both lists as code (i.e. actual lists) and also clarify the logic behind the merging.

Comment: Hey guys! I have updated my question sorry if I was not being clear earlier ><

Comment: How do you differentiate situations when one review has both like and dislike OR when one review has like and the next one - dislike?

Comment: @MariaK each review will start with a Like unless there is no Like it will only have a Dislike like based off my example output

Comment: Here's an example to clarify my previous question: what if we have arrays `["Liked", "Disliked", "Liked", "Disliked"]` and `[7, 10, 8]`. How do we know if the mapping is `7 -> Liked, Disliked, 10 -> Liked, 8 -> Disliked` or `7 -> Liked, 10 -> Disliked, 8 -> Liked, Disliked`? Both seem to satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @MariaK the output that you gave are both wrong in my case. the correct output would be ```7 -> Liked and Disliked , 10 -> Liked and Disliked`` as i mentioned each review would be starting with a ```Liked``` and followed by a ```Disliked``` if there is else it will just go to the next number. 

vice versa if there is only a ```Disliked``` without any ```Like``` before it, the number will just be tied to the ```Disliked```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a consecutive like and dislike should be combined together *greedily*, you could achieve it like this:

```
result = []
i = 0
likes = [like.split()[-1].lower() for like in list1]
for score in list2:
    end = i + 1 + (likes[i:i+2] == ["liked", "disliked"])
    result.append(f"{' and '.join(likes[i:end])} : {score.split()[-1]}")
    i = end

print(result)
```

This assumes that the sizes of the lists are as can be expected with this logic. You may want to add code to verify that this is actually the case (error checking).

Comment: Hey, just what I was looking for! Thanks alot this works against my use case. Im sorry I cannot upvote you. Hope you have a great day ahead!!! ><